# Preload CSS background images [Can't use sprite]

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, preloader

I have this website where the user generates a preview by changing alot of div's background-images. The problem is that the first time I change the background-image to something else, it takes a little while for the image to load, but after that, if I change back, everything looks really smooth.

I was going to use CSS sprites to eliminate this problem, but when I tried it, some browsers almost froze since they couldn't handle that large images.

So my question is, how can I preload these specific background-images, without using CSS sprites?

**EDIT:**

I apologize if I've been unclear. What I'm creating is somewhat of a character creation screen. What I'm trying to do is that when the page loads, the user can select what race they want to be. When they do that, I want a loader to show up and I want all the images connected to that race to be preloaded. When that is complete, I want to remove the loader, and then the user can customize their character further.

When the user customize their character, the background-images on the character div changes to one of the preloaded images. I've tried to load the images with JavaScript using the method **Rustam** described below, but I get the same result. The first time a background-image is shown, it takes a second to load.

Comment: Are all possible images already on your server or do they come from a user upload?

Comment: Not necessarily, normal JavaScript would also be fine.

Answer (score 1):

cache them after pageload with js.

Answer (score 1):

See here: [CSS Only Image Preloading](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-only-image-preloading/) - the key is to load all required images as backgrounds in other divs but the divs are "hidden" off the page.

> Load the image on the element's regular state, only shift it away with
>   background position. Then move the background position to display it
>   on hover.

```
#img1 { background: url(images/img1.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
#img2 { background: url(images/img2.png) no-repeat -9999px -9999px; }
```

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I can't preload ALL the images before the page loads, that would take to long time. I need to be able to load a select number of images during runtime with JavaScript.

I could add these "invisible" divs with JavaScript, but then I won't have any control when the loading is complete, so the problem still stands.

Comment: I think you're still not being clear enough. Exactly when do you want each image to load? Why do you need control of when the image loading is complete? What do you want to happen when each image has loaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you want do it without javascript - the only way to put in html invisible `<img>`. Like this:

`<div style="overflow:hidden;height:0;"><img/><img/><img/><img/></div>`

But div must be **not** hidden by `display:none`, `visibility:hidden` because some browser can no load it in this case.

Comment: Ok, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I can't preload ALL the images before the page loads, that would take to long time. I need to be able to load a select number of images during runtime with JavaScript.

I could add these "invisible" divs with JavaScript, but then I won't have any control when the loading is complete, so the problem still stands.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript way to preload images:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.setAttribute('src', 'image_path');

// Load event
img.onload=function(){ alert("It's loaded!") };
```

Comment: I tried this technique, but even though I loaded all images this way, they still won't appear instantly when I use them as a background-image.

Comment: You used this code after load event of body / document.ready in jQuery?

Comment: Did you see particularly loaded images in Safari?

Comment: Yes. The load code is bound to a button. After I click the button i want to be able to change a div's background image to one of the preloaded images, without it having to load.

Comment: I didn't see them, since i didn't add the to the body, just loaded them. But i logged every load with JS, so i saw the requests.

Comment: What happens if you bind creating of div with backgrounds on after load event? How much is delay?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Web Workers for that and preload all images in the background, in a separate thread. Using this you would not block the Browser UI and when the worker is finished you can use the images.

Take a look here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/